# Multiple items with same class, how to distinguish them with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown list where there are multiple items with class "dropdown" and "menu". On click event I want javascript to find the certain .dropdown that I clicked. Is it possible to implement "this" somewhere on my code and make it work?

```
  $(".dropdown").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      if ($(".menu").is(":visible")) {
        $(".menu").slideUp();
        $(this).find("li").children(".list").addClass("plus").removeClass("minus");
      } else {
        $(".menu").slideDown();
        $(this).find("li").children(".list").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus");
      }
  });
```

Edited afterwards:

So this is my list (please don't pay attention to the fact that "a" is outside of "li"). So I need to find closest "menu" to "dropdown". Already tried closest, find etc. but nothing I tried did the trick. Any suggestions?

```
  <a class="dropdown" href=""><li>Link 1 <div class="plus"></div></li></a>
  <ul class="menu">
  ....
```

Comment: Isn't `$(this)` already doing it? Otherwise try `e.target`.

Comment: share jsfiddle please and as @moonwave99 said you are already using $(this), it means you are getting clicked dropdown element instance

Comment: The problem is that I have a large dropdown list where some items have children items too. When I click "dropdown" all the menus and their children open because they have the same class name. The this.find... part is working fine though.

Comment: I probably should find the closest menu (child ul) element to dropdown (li) element.

Comment: I think your problem is `$(".menu")`, You need to use relation between  "dropdown" and "menu". It would be best if you share HTML

Comment: @Satpal, I think you're right.

Comment: @user3496563, Use `$(this).next('.menu')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery uses CSS selectors so just do `$(".dropdown > .menu")` to select the first `.menu` following a `.dropdown`. or `$(".dropdown .menu:first-child")`

edit:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function()
{
    var theNextMenu = $(this).next(".menu");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace the dropdown with this (reffering to the clicked dropdown). Something like this: $(this > ".menu")?

Answer (score 2):

Within the event handling function, `this` will be set to the element that was clicked.

If that does not help, you should provide more information in your question.